# How to get data from the selected row in javaFX tableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a button that deletes a certain row but it does not delete it from the database. Ounce I reload the `TableView` it reappears. How can I do this please help..

My Controller

```
 @FXML
private Button deleteButton;

private static Connection conn=null;

private ObservableList<UserData> data;

@FXML
private TableView<UserData> clerksTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData,String> ColumnName;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData,String> ColumnEmail;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData,String> ColumnLocation;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData,String> ColumnPassword;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData,String> Columnid;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    populateTable();
}

private void populateTable() {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    try {
        conn = DBconn.DBconnect();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM clerk";
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        UserData userDataInstance;

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            userDataInstance = new UserData(resultSet.getString("id"),resultSet.getString("fullname"),resultSet.getString("email"),resultSet.getString("location"),resultSet.getString("pass"));
            int id = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("id"));
            data.add(userDataInstance);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console" + ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Error",  "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Columnid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData,String>("id"));
    ColumnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData,String>("fullname"));
    ColumnEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData,String>("email"));
    ColumnLocation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData,String>("location"));
    ColumnPassword.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData,String>("password"));

    clerksTableView.setItems(data);


}

public void onDelete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    ObservableList<UserData> selectedRow,allRows;
    allRows = clerksTableView.getItems();
    selectedRow = clerksTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    selectedRow.forEach(allRows :: remove);
}
```

### my .fxml file

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="ViewClerks" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="641.0" prefWidth="660.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.ClerksView">
  <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.7204724409448819" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="121.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="476.0" prefWidth="498.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="264.0" prefWidth="496.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="clerksTableView" layoutX="164.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="291.0" prefWidth="496.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="-32.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Columnid" prefWidth="43.0" text="id" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="ColumnName" prefWidth="160.0" text="Full name" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="ColumnEmail" prefWidth="157.0" text="Email" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="ColumnLocation" prefWidth="145.0" text="Location" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="ColumnPassword" maxWidth="200.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="Password" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="173.0" prefWidth="638.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="ClerksFullname" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="16.0" promptText="Full name" />
                  <TextField fx:id="ClerksEmailAddress" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="51.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="171.0" promptText="Email" />
                  <TextField fx:id="ClerksLocation" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="84.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="171.0" promptText="Location" />
                  <TextField fx:id="ClerksPassword" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="126.0" promptText="Password" />
                  <Button layoutX="502.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addingClerksDetails" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="116.0" stylesheets="@../css/portal.css" text="Add Clerk" />
                  <Separator layoutX="235.0" layoutY="13.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
                  <Label fx:id="successLabel" layoutX="520.0" layoutY="34.0" stylesheets="@../css/portal.css" />
                  <Button fx:id="deleteButton" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDelete" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="130.0" stylesheets="@../css/portal.css" text="Delete Clerk"   textFill="#f50000" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I tried searching online how to get the data for each cell from selected row so as to delete it from my database but to no avail..
Am new to javaFX

more code here

```
public class UserData {
    private SimpleStringProperty fullname;
    private SimpleStringProperty email;
    private SimpleStringProperty location;
    private SimpleStringProperty password;
    private SimpleStringProperty id;


    public UserData(String id, String fullname, String email, String location, String password) {
        this.fullname = new SimpleStringProperty(fullname);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        this.password = new SimpleStringProperty(password);
        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
    }

    public String getfullname() {
        return fullname.get();
    }

    public void setfullname(String fName) {
        fullname.set(fName);
    }
    public StringProperty fullnameProperty() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public String getemail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setemail(String Email) {
        fullname.set(Email);
    }
    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getlocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public void setlocation(String Location) {
        fullname.set(Location);
    }
    public StringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getpassword() {
        return password.get();
    }

    public void setpassword(String Pass) {
        fullname.set(Pass);
    }
    public StringProperty passwordProperty() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setid(String Id) {
        id.set(Id);
    }
    public StringProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... when you remove the item from the table you should probably remove it from the database too... (`DELETE FROM clerk WHERE id=`...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call database to remove the selected row, after that it is automatically delete the row from table.